# emacs perl-mode: indent in hash broken for format key?

Tags: perl, emacs

emacs24 has a weird bug for me ( using perl-mode ),
when I enter a hash containing the key 'format', 
indent breaks for all subsequent lines.

Example:

```
my $hash = {
   foo => 'bar',
   format => 'some',
};

sub some_code {
print "will not indent :(";
};
```

Now hitting "tab" does nothing, neither does auto-indent ( indent-region ).

Any ideas why this might be and how I can fix it?

Comment: Perhaps it thinks you're calling the [`format` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html).

Comment: that seems like a good bet. Did not know that. Not sure how to fix this, but definitely helpful, thank you! Perl is parsing it as intended, though - so the perl parser knows what I want...

Comment: The workaround is to quote your hash key: `'format' => 'some',`

Comment: Yes, it definitely thinks it is format, if I put a '.' on the next line, emacs works fine ( the parser does not like it, unsurprisingly ). So, going with quotes I am, thanks!

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this bug with Emacs 24.2.2.  It indents properly even without the quotes around `format`.  Exactly which version of Emacs are you using?  Does the bug still show up if you run `emacs -Q`?

Comment: a) format is a keyword. b) there is a much better perl mode: cperl mode. it has syntax highlighting for regexen and some other nice features (and is also shipped with many emacs distributions).

Comment: I am quite happy with perl mode otherwise, I tried cperl mode but did not like it so much.  version is '24.3.1'.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with emacs 24.4.51.2 (Aquamacs 3.2) with perl-mode nor cperl-mode.  Perhaps you just need to upgrade emacs or your perl-mode.el?  Or perhaps it's something in your perl-mode configuration?

Comment: I have decided to update, as you suggested, but not come around to it yet, it should help, since I do not recall making major changes from the original config, and then I hope it is settled. Not a major issue, but strange, and somewhat annoying. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, Emacs-23 and Emacs-24 both handle this just fine, so I think the problem is linked to a customization in your `~/.emacs`.

Try it with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Nope, no luck there, sorry. Still have not updated, though, this may take a bit since I am busy and the workaround is doing ok.

Comment: I doubt upgrading will make any difference.

Comment: I see why you might think so, but several people here do not have that problem, so it must be either the version or some part of the config. Now that I know it can be fixed, it will be eventually. I will post when that's the case.

Comment: I have now switched to an emacs25 ( 25.0.50 ) version. No problems there. Removing my entire config had no effect, but I will not figure out what the problem really was anymore, since I am now working with another version. Thanks all for your time and effort.